# How i find out which person stayed maximum nights? Name and total how many days?

Tags: python-3.x

How i find out which person stayed maximum nights? Name and total how many days? (date format MM/DD)

for example

text file contain's

```
Robin 01/11 01/15
Mike 02/10 02/12
John 01/15 02/15
```

output expected

```
('john', 30 )
```

my code

```
def longest_stay(fpath):
    with open(fpath,'r')as f_handle:
        stay=[]

        for line in f_handle:
            name, a_date, d_date = line.strip().split()
            diff = datetime.strptime(d_date, "%m/%d") -datetime.strptime(a_date, "%m/%d")
            stay.append(abs(diff.days+1))
    return name,max(stay)
```

It always return first name.

Answer (score 1):

This can also be implemented using pandas. I think it will much simpler using pandas.

One issue I find is that how you want to handle when you have many stayed for max nights. I have addressed that in the following code.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime as dt

def longest_stay(fpath):
    # Reads the text file as Dataframe
    data = pd.read_csv(fpath + 'test.txt', sep=" ", header = None) 

    # adding column names to the Data frame
    data.columns = ['Name', 'a_date', 'd_date'] 

    # Calculating the nights for each customer
    data['nights'] = datetime.strptime(d_date, "%m/%d") - datetime.strptime(a_date, "%m/%d") 

    # Slicing the data frame by applying the condition and getting the Name of the customer and nights as a tuple (as expected)
    longest_stay = tuple( data.ix[data.nights == data.nights.max(), {'Name', 'nights'}])

    # In case if many stayed for the longest night. Returns a list of tuples.
    longest_stay = [tuple(x) for x in longest_stay]

    return longest_stay
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code fails but not storing the first name, it is because `name` is going to be set to the last name in the file because you only store the days as you go, hence you always see the last name.

You also add + 1 which does not seem correct as you should not be adding or including the last day as the person does not stay that night. Your code would actually output `('John', 32)` the correct name by chance because it is the last in your sample file and the day off by 1.

Just keep track of the best which includes the name and day count as you go using the days stayed as the measure and return that at the end:

```
from datetime import datetime
from csv import reader

def longest_stay(fpath):
    with open(fpath,'r')as f_handle:
        mx,best  = None, None
        for name, a_date, d_date in reader(f_handle,delimiter=" "):
            days = (datetime.strptime(d_date, "%m/%d") - datetime.strptime(a_date, "%m/%d")).days 
            # first iteration or we found 
            if best is None or mx < days:
                best = name, days
    return best
```

Outout:

```
In [13]: cat test.txt
Robin 01/11 01/15
Mike 02/10 02/12
John 01/15 02/15
In [14]: longest_stay("test.txt")
# 31 days not including the last day as a stay
Out[14]: ('John', 31)
```

You only need to use abs if the format is not always in the format start-end but be aware would could get the wrong output using the abs value if your dates had years.